# Android how to combine textMultiLine and actionNext on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view, ime

I just want to do something VERY simple:

if i have an edit text, i want the max to be 5 lines of text in height of the text box, and i was it such that when the user is typying something, and then they hit "Enter" or "Next", i create a new line for them but annotate something in the beginning. i.e. -> if i want an edit text that starts with:

`1.`

if the user types "hi", then the edit text would appear to be:

`1. hi`

but now if the user then hits "Enter"/"Next", then i want the text to be:

```
1. hi
2.
```

where i automatically fill in the "2." with a new line.

here's how my edit text looks:

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/something"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:text="1. "/>
```

and of course, i provide a custom EditorAction for that EditText's `setOnEditorActionListener`, like so:

```
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        private int mNumberOfLines = 1;
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                mNumberOfLines++;
                editText.setText(editText.getText() + "\n" + mNumberOfLines + ". ");
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

.... Why does this not work? if i use `text` instead of `textMultiLine`, then the editText doesn't recognize the newline characters. but if i use `textMultiLine`, then the key action for `IME_ACTION_NEXT` doesn't get recognized. wtf?